# access methods from the vue current component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-events

Can any one guide or suggest how to resolve this below issue.
Use Case: Trying to implement notification component
Scenario: I am trying to call a method or change the state of the data on triggering of event in Vue.
I have defined the event listener on mounted function and trying to access one of the method.

[image]

Basically, the alert within event function is getting triggered, where as alert inside method is not getting triggered, and even any data manipulation is not executing even with in event function.

Where am i missing? is it incorrect to alter state within Event listener?
Basically i am trying to implement notification feature which automatically disappear after few seconds

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Girish

Answer (score 1):

There is another reason,`this` inside callback function is not Vue component. You can assign `var self = this` and use inside the callback, or use arrow function.

```
mounted: function () {
  var self = this
  EventBus.$on('show', function () {
    self.test()
    self.show = true
  })
},
methods: {
  test () {
    console.log('Inside methods')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ittus, It worked:), But just wondering why "this" wont work inside Eventhandler

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the spelling error instead of

```
method: {}
```

, use `methods: {}`
Example:

```
Error.
method: {
test: function () {
alert('Inside Method');
}

correct.
methods: {
test: function () {
alert('inside method);
}
}
```

I know it does not have much to do with the question, but be careful when using the event bus, it would be as if you had a speaker, and shouted in the middle of a crowd the name of a person.
Example:
eventbus says Hamilton in the midst of a crowd of 10,000 people.
How many Hamiltons can you have in the middle of this crowd? Use something more specific, such as parent-child communication, avoid using the event bus.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, yeah, my bad. silly spelling mistake:(. Yeah i agree to you on Event Bus, an Global Event bus, may cause some maintainability issue, if not documented correctly. Fortunately i am using a local event handlers.:)